# Get asp:Button Text into a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am trying to accomplish the task of changing the background image of an asp:Button (user control) based on the Text. It's basically a toggle operation (on/off) background image.

I want to get the Text element into an int variable in  my javaScript function using getElementByID. But this doesn't seem to work. Here is my javascript + asp.net code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ButtonControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUI.ButtonControl" %>
<link href="Content/ButtonStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleButtonImage()
    {

        **THE ERROR IS HERE**
        var btnValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=Button.ClientID%>').value);

        //if Text value greater than one then display image
        if (btnValue > 1)
        {
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("#AcumenButton").click(function ()
                {
                    $("#AcumenButton").addClass("buttonBackgroundOn");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }

        // else no image
        else
        {
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("#Button").click(function ()
                {
                    $("#Button").addClass("buttonBackgroundOff");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }

    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="3" Width="7.2%" Height="79px" />
```

Here is my CSS for both the classes:

```
.buttonBackgroundOn 
{
    background: url(/Images/BlobOnButtonImg.PNG) no-repeat !important;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
}

buttonBackgroundOff 
{
    background: url(/Images/PlainBorderButtonImg.PNG) no-repeat !important;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The page that uses this user control has the following in it's .cs class:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "js", "toggleButtonBorder();", false);
```

I really don't know where I am going wrong. Any advise?

Comment: What error do you get?
What does document.getElementById('<%=AcumenButton.ClientID%>').value return?

Comment: you are missing the dot in the class "buttonBackgroundOff", it must be ".buttonBackgroundOff"

Comment: There is no error as such. The button is rendered plain. And the clientID for some odd reason is returned as AcumenButton. How can I access the Text?

Comment: @MCSI: Thank you for your good eye. Didn't solve the problem though because I don't enter the else condition at all.

Comment: @Remy- I changed <%=AcumenButton.ClientID%> to <%=AcumenButton.Text%> but no success.

Comment: @Remy- The clientID returned is actually AcumenButtonControl1_AcumenButton where AcumenButtonControl1 is the ID of the user control (on the .aspx page). Is there a way to call this within the user control ascx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I figured out that JavaScript may not be the best tool to be used here. Instead, I set the CssClass for the button in the user control ascx.cs class to give me the desired result hence:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButtonImage(int.Parse(ButtonText));            
    }
public int ToggleButtonImage(int btnTextValue) 
        {
            int btnTextVal = btnTextValue;

            if (btnTextVal > 1)
            {
                Button.CssClass = "buttonBackgroundOn";
            }
            else if (btnTextVal <= 1)
            {
                Button.CssClass = "buttonBackgroundOff";
            }
            return btnTextVal;
        }
```

This was so much simpler to do.

Comment: Yeah unless you are changing the button text on the client side with JavaScript, just manipulating the css-class in the code behind is a lot easier to implement & maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
            {


        **THE ERROR IS HERE**
        var btnValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=AcumenButton.ClientID%>').value);

        //if Text value greater than one then display image
        if (btnValue > 1)
        {
             $("#AcumenButton").click(function ()
                {
                    $("#AcumenButton").addClass("buttonBackgroundOn");
                    return false;
                });

        }

        // else no image
        else
        {

                $("#AcumenButton").click(function ()
                {
                    $("#AcumenButton").addClass("buttonBackgroundOff");
                    return false;
                });

        }

    });
</script>
```